# multirow select - remove selected option from other select

Tags: html, angular, typescript, select, frontend

i have a multirow select that bind to the same list of option. what i need to accomplish is that when one option is selected into a select than this option need to be hidden to the other select. i started to write the code but i0m stuck at this point:

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/NM4Tj4mrSV6p0Oa0?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1

The main issue here is that since all the options are bind to the same list when i remove the selected value than the same is removed from the selected one.
Probably I need to use 2 different list.. but I don't really know how to do this.
can someone help me to complete the 'onclick' function  in order to obtain what i need.? 
thank you.

Comment: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/BFf8KNiFkNjccyuP?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1

Comment: @yurzui That works perfectly! thank you very much! you made my day :)